# Opencart (Error while creating local instance of OC with php 5.2)

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, opencart

Need help to create local instance of OC with previously existing customized code of OC.
I am able to login but after clicking on some windows it throws common error of mysql, i.e

**Error No: 1054** (common error)

[image]

```
SELECT a.brands FROM user_group a, user b 
WHERE b.user_id = 1 AND b.user_group_id = a.user_group_id
```

(query gets different according to the window).

Comment: Which OC version are you using?

Comment: This OC code is so much customized that I am not able to find its version also. I guess its OC 1.4  and I am pretty sure also its not OC 1.5 and above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out why its giving the above error.
When creating instance of Opecart, we have to initially give blank database name when running install folder of opencart. Then default db gets created with the name. Later we have to import the db we want to restore.

This does the trick.